# Google Place Autocomplete Address Form with Latitude & Longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using [Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=fr) but unfortunately I am not good with Google Map APIs and jQuery.

Now I have implemented code in my own HTML and what I tried to add selected place `latitude` & `longitude` to text box but don't know something is wrong in my code. I am getting same latitude & longitude every time.

I have two more queries that I want to correct in my customized code:

1. If user select any place then add latitude & longitude to text box.
2. Latitude & Longitude getting in text box after few seconds.

**My modified code is:**

```
// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude            
        );

        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        alert(latitude);
        alert(longitude);
        document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
        document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;

        autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,geolocation));
    });
  }  
}
```

My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vjwsH/

I feel happy if you try to help me.

Thanks

Comment: Is that what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/q8XS6/

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes exactly but why I am getting two times lat & long from text box.

Comment: The autocomplete input has a `onfocus` attribute (in your code) that triggers `geolocate()` function which I replaced in my example with the first jQuery statement (lines 4 to 6). Just remove it if you don't need that.